# Can anyone please explain what is happening in this XSLT code?

Tags: xml, xslt, mulesoft, ibm-datapower

I am working in a project (datapower to mule migration) I am beginner in XSLT and have no experience. Can anyone please help me to understand the working of this xslt file so that I can migrate it into mule API.
This is my XSLT file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
     xmlns:fin="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/policymanagement/2009/01/financialservicesagreement"
     xmlns:par="http://schemas.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/policymanagement/2009/01/party"
     xmlns:pol="http://webservices.zurich.com/zsoa/fig/policymanagement/policyinquiry-v4_0"
     exclude-result-prefixes="dp" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="plcynum" select="dp:variable('var://context/PIPE/pc')" />

    <dp:set-variable name="'var://context/PIPE/LP'" value="'LEARNER'S PERMIT'" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--<xsl:template match="ntig[descendant::term[. = '']]"/>-->
    <!-- <xsl:template match="langSet[not(descendant::term[. != ''])]"/>-->

    <xsl:template match="fin:basicPolicy[
                           descendant::fin:policyNumber[
                             normalize-space(.) 
                             != dp:variable('var://context/PIPE/pc')
                           ]
                         ]"/>

    <!--xsl:template match="pol:houseHoldMembers[not(descendant::par:primeRole[ normalize-space(.) !='CLIENT IS A DRIVER' or  normalize-space(.) !='EXCLUDED DRIVER' or  normalize-space(.) != dp:variable('var://context/PIPE/LP')])]"></xsl:template-->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: At least at a tag for datapower as otherwise you won't find people knowing what the proprietary datapower extensions used are supposed to achieve.

Comment: @Alejandro Please do not edit OP's code - you don't know what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a stylesheet with two template rules. The first rule says the default action is to copy everything from the input unchanged. The second rule (because it's empty) says that when elements matching a particular pattern are encountered, they should be dropped. Specifically, a `basicPolicy` element should be dropped if contains a `policyNumber` that meets particular criteria; I don't understand the criteria because they are defined using a non-standard Datapower extension.

Comment: *"It's a stylesheet with two template rules."* We don't know that. It's a beginning of a stylesheet, with no closing tag.

Comment: The OP said "this is my XSLT file" so I read it as being complete.

Comment: If there is 3 basicPolicy  element inside different elements then will all 3 be dropped ?

Comment: Thankyou so much Michael Kay